# Find the closest previous element that matches a certain pattern in R

Tags: r, text-parsing

Given such a vector:

```r
c("node 1",
  "primary",
  "sports, improve",
  "music, improve",
  "painting, improve",
  "surrogate",
  "music",
  "node 2", 
  "primary", 
  "music, improve",
  "painting, improve",
  "node 3", 
  "primary",
  "sports, improve")
```

I want to get each name under each "primary" and its corresponding node as a single string. For example: for the first node, which is the first element in the vector above ("node 1"), there should be three outputs: "node 1 sports", "node 1 music", "node 1 painting". For "node 2" there should be two : "node 2 music", "node 2 painting". The data is much bigger than the given vector, so indexing and manually generating strings is not preferred. My initial thought is to find each element that contains "improve" with grepl. I can't find a way to assign the elements found with grepl to its corresponding node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a group based on the occurrence of 'node', get the `cumsum` of logical vector, `split` the vector 'v1' into a `list`, `paste` the first element with the substring of elements that have 'improve' and `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
stack(lapply(split(v1, cumsum(grepl('node', v1))), 
   function(x) paste(x[1], sub(",.*", "", x[grep('improve', x)]))))[2:1]
```

-output

```
#  ind          values
#1   1   node 1 sports
#2   1    node 1 music
#3   1 node 1 painting
#4   2    node 2 music
#5   2 node 2 painting
#6   3   node 3 sports
```

Comment: This gets the correct answer only when the Node numbers increase one by one starting from 1. If node numbers are 1,2,5,6 it does not get it right

Comment: @moli No, that is not the case

Comment: How can I modify the answer for cases such that some nodes do not have a "primary" under them. Should I create a new question for this or modify this question's example vector so that it includes such a case?

Comment: @moli Can you create a new question as it may needs some modification

Comment: I made a new question about the issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680434/finding-the-corresponding-pattern-for-another-pattern-in-a-vector-r

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, could you check a question I posted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764330/map-a-list-of-dataframe-columns-into-another-dataframe-r