# Finding the corresponding pattern for another pattern in a vector R

Tags: r

Given such a vector:

```r
c("node 1",
  "primary",
  "sports, improve",
  "music, improve",
  "painting, improve",
  "surrogate, agree",
  "music, agree",
  "node 2", 
  "primary", 
  "music, improve",
  "painting, improve",
  "node 3", 
  "primary",
  "sports, improve",
  "node 4",
  "surrogate",
  "music, agree",
  "sports, agree",
  "node 5",
  "node 6",
  "primary",
  "painting, improve")
```

I want to get each name under each "primary" element and its corresponding node as a single string. The corresponding node is the closest node name before a "primary" element. For example: for the first node, which is the first element in the vector above ("node 1"), there should be three outputs: "node 1 sports", "node 1 music", "node 1 painting". For "node 2" there should be two: "node 2 music", "node 2 painting". The data is much bigger than the given vector, so indexing and manually generating strings is not preferred. My initial thought is to find each element that contains "improve" with grepl. Some nodes do not have "primary" under them and they should not be assigned a string. The expected output is:

```r
"node 1 sports"
"node 1 music"
"node 1 painting"
"node 2 music"
"node 2 painting"
"node 3 sports"
"node 6 painting"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we can check for the `length` of the subset in `base R`, `Filter` those `NULL` elements and `stack` it to a two column `data.frame`

```
stack(Filter(Negate(is.null),
   lapply(split(v1, cumsum(grepl('node', v1))), 
   function(x) {
      x1 <- sub(",.*", "", x[grep('improve', x)])
          if(length(x1) > 0) paste(x[1], x1)
  })))[2:1]
```

-output

```
#  ind          values
#1   1   node 1 sports
#2   1    node 1 music
#3   1 node 1 painting
#4   2    node 2 music
#5   2 node 2 painting
#6   3   node 3 sports
#7   6 node 6 painting
```

Details:

1. `split` the `vector` ('v1') into a `list` of vectors

   ```
   split(v1, cumsum(grepl('node', v1)))
   ```

The `grepl` returns TRUE wherever 'node' element is found, `cumsum` increments the count by 1 where TRUE values are (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0).  This can be used as a index variable for `split`ing the vector

2. Loop over the `list` with `lapply`
3. Using anonymous `lambda` function (`function(x)`) the 'x' are the vector elements values in the `list`, get those elements having 'improve' substring, and remove the substring from `,` to all other characters (`.*`)

   ```
   x1 <- sub(",.*", "", x[grep('improve', x)])
   ```
4. Create a logical expression to check if we have any element in 'x1' with  `length`, `if` the `length` is greater than 0, then we `paste` the first element of vector with 'x1'
5. `stack` to a two column data.frame after `Filter`ing out the `NULL` `list` elements (`is.null` - returns TRUE for NULL, `Negate` changes TRUE to FALSE and FALSE to TRUE)

#### data

```
v1 <- c("node 1", "primary", "sports, improve", "music, improve", 
"painting, improve", 
"surrogate, agree", "music, agree", "node 2", "primary", "music, improve", 
"painting, improve", "node 3", "primary", "sports, improve", 
"node 4", "surrogate", "music, agree", "sports, agree", "node 5", 
"node 6", "primary", "painting, improve")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr); library(stringr)
my_nodes %>%
  separate(src_vec, c("primary", "secondary"), sep = ", ", extra = "drop") %>%
  mutate(node_detect = str_detect(primary, "node"),
         node = paste("node", cumsum(node_detect))) %>%
  # keep the nodes marked "improve"
  filter(!node_detect, secondary == "improve") %>%
  mutate(result = paste(node, primary)) %>%
  pull(result)


#[1] "node 1 sports"   "node 1 music"    "node 1 painting" "node 2 music"    "node 2 painting" "node 3 sports"   "node 6 painting"
```

source data

```
my_nodes <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                       src_vec = c("node 1",
  "primary",
  "sports, improve",
  "music, improve",
  "painting, improve",
  "surrogate, agree",
  "music, agree",
  "node 2", 
  "primary", 
  "music, improve",
  "painting, improve",
  "node 3", 
  "primary",
  "sports, improve",
  "node 4",
  "surrogate",
  "music, agree",
  "sports, agree",
  "node 5",
  "node 6",
  "primary",
  "painting, improve"))
```